# sequential fade using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to div to fade one by one

http://jsfiddle.net/uz2rm8jy/2/

```
<div id="w">

<div class="one"></div>

    <div class="two"></div>

    <div class="three"></div>


</div>

$(function() {
$('#w').each(function(i) {
$(this).delay((i++) * 500).fadeTo(1000, 1); });
});
```

not sure why this doesn't work in my case, is my fade doing right? or I should try css() instead?

Comment: You almost had it, you need `opacity: 0;` on your elements for the `fadeTo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in the wrong value to `fadeTo`. If you want to fade the elements OUT, remember that `1` is fully opaque/visible while `0` is transparent/invisible. If you change that parameter to `0` it should work

```
$(this).delay((i++) * 500).fadeTo(1000, 0); })
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uz2rm8jy/1/)

Comment: @JohnSt did you read my answer? The second parameter you pass to `fadeTo` should be `0` instead of `1`

Comment: @JohnSt mate you're "new fiddle" is still passing `0` as the opacity parameter. Are you drunk?

Comment: @JohnSt also you're "new fiddle" is iterating through ONLY one element which is the container element...`#w`. It should be iterating through the child elements...`#w div`. Here's your new fiddle working...http://jsfiddle.net/uz2rm8jy/5/

Comment: can it be like reverse? fadeIn instead of fade away.

Comment: @JohnSt yes, it can. But, you should post a separate question if you have more questions rather than  polluting this one with off-topic questions

Comment: but take a look at this bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039526/sequential-animation-with-animate-css-and-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You need `opacity: 0;` on your `div`'s for the `fadeTo`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz2rm8jy/6/)